# Xamarin Install Issue

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Running into a super vague error when I attempt to install Xamarin.

> Installation of archive
>   'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.2.11.msi'
>   failed with exception. Exception type:
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException Full stack trace: at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>   path, Boolean needsPrivileges) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String
>   url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem
>   download) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber) at WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()

Windows 10 box with VS 2013 Premium.  It was previously erroring as I reached the Android SDK, but now it doesn't seem to mention that any more.  Anyone else run into something similar/have suggestions for better debugging?
So far C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Universal logs have not shed any additional light.

Comment: Make sure you are running VS2013 Update 2 per the [system requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements). Try right-clicking the .msi and running as admin. If that does not help, post the full [installer logs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#ide-and-installer-logs).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it manually i.e installing each component separately.
Refer this link : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/